# Passing external function of multiple variables as a function of one variable in Fortran

Tags: function, fortran

I'm trying to use routines in `QUADPACK` to perform numerical integration. The routines expect functions to be passed as `REAL,EXTERNAL`, so I don't have the liberty of using pointers or whatever else.

Is it possible to alias a function `f(x,a,b,...)` as being a function `f(x)` for the routine that expects a function of x only? Much like what one would accomplish in `MATLAB` with `@(x)f(x,a,b,...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make similar tricks with functions in Fortran directly. You also cannot return a closure in Fortran. Just write a wrapper.

```
function wrap_f(x) result(res)
  ...
  res = f(a,b,...)
end function
```

It can be an internal or module function and get `a` and `b` by the host association or it can use the module containing `a` and `b`.

If you want to pass the function as an actual argument, it cannot be an internal procedure in up to Fortran 2003, but only in Fortran 2008. But it works in recent versions of gfortran and ifort. For better portability use a module.

Comment: Well, it wasn't that clear to me what the OP want's to do with that function, originally I thought f is from that library.

Comment: Sorry, `f` is a function that I'm writing, to be passed to the quadrature routine. Either way this is helpful. Basically, `wrap_f` cannot take `a` and `b` as arguments directly?

Comment: Exactly, it must have access to them by some other way (hist association, use association).

Answer (score 2):

I can show a nice solution for this problem. I am also a former MATLAB user and when switching to FORTRAN you miss function handles haha. I solved your problem in this way:

```
module

     private
     public    :: f , g

     real(kind=RP)   :: a0,b0,c0,...

     contains
         function f(x,a,b,c,d,...) 
               implicit none
               real(kind=RP)  :: x,a,b,c,d,...
               real(kind=RP)  :: f
!              Here you define your function
               f = ...

         end function f

         function g(x)
               implicit none
               real(kind=RP)  :: x , g

!              Here you call "f" function with the frozen variables *0
               g = f(x,a0,b0,c0,...)
         end function g

!        We said that parameters were private 
!     (to avoid to be modified from the outside, which can be dangerous, 
!     so we define functions to set their values

         subroutine setValues(a,b,c,...)
               implicit none
               real(kind=RP)   :: a,b,c,...

               a0 = a
               b0 = b
               c0 = c

          end subroutine setValues



end module
```