# Fortran minimization of a function with additional arguments

Tags: matlab, fortran

In fortran I have an external optimization routine that takes as an input the `function f(x)` and the starting point and returns the value for local minimum. For example if the function is called minimum:

```
minimum(f,x0,xopt)
```

The problem is that the function I need to minimize depends on some additional arguments that are not part of the minimization routine: `f(x,data)`.

How can I overcome this issue.
In matlab I would use anonymous function

```
g=@(x) f(x,data)

minimum(g, x0, xopt)
```

However as I understant in fortran 90 there are no anonymous function.

Thanks.

Comment: Arjen Markus's book (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Fortran-Practice-Arjen-Markus/dp/1107603471/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1412938088&sr=1-1&keywords=arjen+Markus) covers this topic at some length.  Get yourself a copy, the rest of it is good stuff too.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24127313/3157076

Answer (score 7):

You don't need anonymous functions for this. Your Matlab example is also not anonymous in the end, it has a name `g`.

Fortran internal functions are of great use here (Fortran 2008 feature, but supported in gfortran and ifort, not supported in Solaris Studio):

```
call minimum(g, x0, xopt)

contains

  real function g(x)
    real, intent(in) :: x
    g = f(x,data)
  end function

end
```

Comment: This is simple enough if `data` is a compile-time constant or `f(x,data)` is an external function. Is there a way to set the values of `data` within `minimum()` for multiple uses?

Comment: @jvriesem I don't really understand what you are asking. `data` can be anything at all. `f` is just some function, external or from a module.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now if `f()` is entirely external. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea from MATLAB in that you can create another function that returns `f`'s value while encapsulating `data`.  Two options come to mind.

If `data` is fixed at compile-time, you can wrap `f` in a module that uses it:

```
Module Foo
    type(blah) :: data = ...
    Contains
        Real Function f(x)
          ! data is visible here.
        End Function f
End Module Foo
```

If `data` is more dynamic through user-input or calculation, you can define a function that returns `data` and call it from within `f`:

```
Real Function f(x)
  ...
  Type(blah), Save :: data
  Logical, Save :: data_not_loaded = .True.
  If data_not_loaded Then
    data = load_data(...)
    data_not_loaded = .False.
  End If
  ...
End Function f
```

Instead of a `load_data()` function, you could also make a registry-like subroutine to first set the value of `data` earlier in the program and then retrieve `data` from within `f`.  However, the logic in `f` won't change that much.

There might also be a method using procedure pointers, but I've never used that feature in Fortran, so I may be wrong.