# Using functions as arguments - how to call?

Tags: function, fortran, function-parameter

I have the following code, where I call a function from a subroutine, all of them in the same module:

```
      module mymodule
      implicit none
      contains  

      subroutine mycode
      real :: y0(3), a = 0.0, b = 1.0
      integer :: i, N = 10
      real, allocatable :: y(:,:)
      y0(:) = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
      y = AB2(od, a, b, N, y0)
      do i = 1, N
          print *, y(:,i)
      end do      
      end subroutine mycode

      function AB2(f, a, b, N, y0)
          real, allocatable :: AB2(:,:)
          interface
              function f(x, y)
                  real, allocatable :: f(:)
                  real, intent(in) :: x, y(:)
              end function
          end interface
          real, intent(in) :: a, b
          integer, intent(in) :: N
          real, intent(in) :: y0(:)
          real :: xn0, xn1, step
          real, allocatable :: yn0(:), yn1(:)
          integer :: i
          allocate(AB2(size(y0),N))
          step = (b-a)/(N-1)
          AB2(:,1) = y0
          AB2(:,2) = y0 + step*f(a, y0)
          do i = 3, N
              xn0 = a+(i-2)*step
              xn1 = a+(i-1)*step
              yn0 = AB2(:,i-2)
              yn1 = AB2(:,i-1)
              AB2(:,i) = AB2(:,i-1) + step*(3.0/2.0*f(xn1,yn1)
     &             -0.5*f(xn0,yn0))
          end do
      end function

      function od(x, y)
          real, allocatable :: od(:)
          real, intent(in) :: x, y(:)
          allocate(od(3))
          od(1) =  x + y(1)
          od(2) = -y(3) - y(2) - x
          od(3) =  x - y(1) + y(3)
      end function

      end module mymodule
```

If I want to give another parameter to the function od, say c, I have to include it on this line

```
real, intent(in) :: x, c, y(:)
```

and also

```
   function od(x,c,y)
```

However, where do I provide the value for this argument? There is no option in the call

```
y = AB2(od, a, b, N, y0)
```

Comment: What error message do you get? How do you call your function? some more details (argument list, return value etc.) of the function are required.

Comment: Please show the complete code. Not just a module, but also the program that uses it. Compile your code with error checking debugging options like `gfortran -g -traceback -Wall -fcheck=all` and show the **complete** output. Your current error message is useless. If those  options I showed don't help, you should at least identify at which line of code does the crash happen.

Comment: Why do you even make the function to return an allocatable array? Let it just return fixed-size array, it is simpler. Also, why is `N=3` and `od` size 3? Shouldn't they be compatible?

Comment: Maybe need `-standard-semantics` (or `-assume realloc_lhs`) because auto-reallocation of allocatable arrays are used ? (e.g. yn0 = AB2(:,i-2)).

Comment: @roygvib did you manage to get it running?

Comment: Yes, it ran without segfault with the above options (for ifort) or gfortran-7.2 (without options). Attaching "-check all" also shows the run-time error message that "y is not allocated" etc.

Comment: What version of Intel Fortran are you using? If an old one, there may be different problems... (FYI I'm using v14--16, which seem OK.)

Comment: I am using v11.1. The thing is I don't get any error, but warnings. What do you recommend to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you try compiling `ifort -assume realloc_lhs yourcode.f90`? Because I don't have v11.1 in hand, I can't test it right now... If this does not work, we may need explicit `allocate()` statement for `y`, `yn0`, `yn1`, etc.

Comment: If you are using Intel please compile with `-g -traceback -warn -check`. I recommend to use them always when developing or debugging.

Comment: @francescalus I've been using ifort-14 and 16.0.2 with "-check all", then the run-time error is "forrtl: severe (408): fort: (8): Attempt to fetch from allocatable variable Y when it is not allocated" (which goes away with "-assume realloc_lhs"). FYI, ifort14-16 (with -assume...), gfortran-7.2, PGI17.4 (with -Mallocatable=03), and Oracle/Sun12.5 all give the same numerical results.

Comment: @Hans If you possibly have gfortran-4.8 on your machine, it may be useful to try "gfortran -frealloc-lhs yourcode.f".

Comment: Alright, now it works. I have another question about the input parameters (I just edited the post)

Comment: Your question is now very different. Since you have no answer yet, it is not a big problem, but please rewrite your question completely about the new problem. Make the whole question about the **Another question** and change the title as well. Remove the old problem, it is not worth keeping it there.

Comment: I just changed the question! ;)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297170/fortran-minimization-of-a-function-with-additional-arguments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127313/passing-external-function-of-multiple-variables-as-a-function-of-one-variable-in?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714406/implementing-anonymous-functions-in-fortran and other related questions. This might be a duplicate.

Comment: I had a look but I couldn't understand. My question is, why should I y = AB2(od, a, b, N, y0) and not y = AB2(od(c), a, b, N, y0) ? Why is this not possible in FORTRAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer does not try to duplicate answers to [Fortran minimization of a function with additional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297170/fortran-minimization-of-a-function-with-additional-arguments) [Passing external function of multiple variables as a function of one variable in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127313/passing-external-function-of-multiple-variables-as-a-function-of-one-variable-in?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [Implementing anonymous functions in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714406/implementing-anonymous-functions-in-fortran) but to introduce the problem on a very basic level.

Suppose you have a function `AB2` and another small function `od`.

They are used in such a way that `AB2` accepts `od` as an argument, so you call

```
y = AB2(od)
```

the functions look like

```
real function AB2(f)
  interface
    real function f(x)
      real x
    end function
  end interface
  ... call f(x) here ...
end function

real function od(x)
  real x
end function
```

You need to pass additional data `c` to `od`. How to do that?

You cannot just change `od` by adding an argument for `c` and keep `AB2` unchanged. `AB2` contains a description of the interface of the argument `f` and `od(x,c)` would not be compatible with `f(x)`.

Also, you would not be able  to pass the data to `AB2`. You certainly cannot do

```
y = AB2(od(c))
```

by doing `od(c)` you are computing a number by calling `od(x)` you would then try to pass this number to `AB2` instead of the function that should be passed.

There are several ways how to mitigate this. They are described in the answers linked above. I will show one simple possibility.

Let's say we nave have function `od(b,x)` and wee need to pass `c` to `b`, but we don't know how to do that with our `AB2`.

```
 real function od(b,x)
   real b, x
 end function
```

In our calling code we create a wrapper function that calls `od` with `c` for us. It can be an internal function or a module function. And we pass the `wrapper` to `AB2`.

```
subroutine caller(c)
  y = AB2(wrapper)
contains
  real function wrapper(x)
    real x
    !we must be able to see c from here, by host association or by using a module
    wrapper = od(c,x)
  end function
end subroutine
```