# Taking average of function over two variables

Tags: fortran, fortran90

So I have a function `f(x, y, t)` that I can evaluate at `x`, `y`, and `t` over a certain interval. If I fix one of the variables, let's use `y`, the function becomes a function of `x` and `t`, let's call that `g(x, t)`. I know how to get the average of that over an interval of `x`, which I can plot as a function of `t`.

```
! I use fortran90. assume all variables are valid

foo = 0.0

do i = 1, n
  do j = 1, n
    foo = foo + g(x(j), t(j))
  end do

  write(*,*) t(i), foo/n
end do
```

where `x(j)` is an array of the possible `x`'s in the interval.

I'm trying to extend this so that I can also take the average over an interval of `y`, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I used a general example; I can post the actual code but it'll be confusing.

Comment: If `f` is meant to represent a mathemtatical function then this approach is an exceptionally poor way to calculate its average.  But if you don't care about that and just want to ask about the technical aspects of going from one to two dimensions, then see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24127313.

Comment: @francescalus Good catch... I think this is a duplicate question, then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing external function of multiple variables as a function of one variable in Fortran](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127313/passing-external-function-of-multiple-variables-as-a-function-of-one-variable-in)

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two options:

1. Use `f(x, y, t)` and provide the (constant) `y` along with the other variables, or
2. Write a wrapper routine `g(x, t)` that uses a constant `y`, either set as compile time or using a global variable. For the latter case you could use a module such as

```
module wrapper

  implicit none
  integer :: fixedY

contains

  function f(x,y,t)
    ! Declarations missing
    ! f = ...
  end function

  function g(x,t)
    ! Declarations missing
    g = f(x, fixedY, t)
  end function
end module
```

In the main program, you first need to set `fixedY` and then call `g`:

```
program test
  use wrapper, only: g, fixedY
  implicit none

  ! Set fixedY
  fixedY = 2

  print *, g(1, 3)
end program
```

You still need to modify this to get the average, for instance, by using a loop (as you did in the code snippet).