# Passing one more parameter to function in addition to allowed arguments

Tags: function, fortran, arguments

I try to employ `vegas` routine (by G.P. Lepage) on Fortran90 to calculate multidimensional integral from function of 7 arguments and 1 parameter.

I took a code of this subroutine `vegas` in famous book Numerical Recipes in Fortran90. Here is declaration of the subroutine:

`SUBROUTINE vegas(region,func,init,ncall,itmx,nprn,tgral,sd,chi2a)`

The second argument is described as

> user-supplied d-dimensional function `func` over a rectangular volume specified by `region`, a vector of length 2d consisting of d “lower left” coordinates of the region followed by d “upper right” coordinates.

So, here is my question: how can I pass to this function `func` one extra argument that is a parameter in my function. Accordingly to description of the function it has exactly as many arguments as there are integration variables (d = 7 in my case) while I need to pass one more argument to this function.

Solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing external function of multiple variables as a function of one variable in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127313/passing-external-function-of-multiple-variables-as-a-function-of-one-variable-in)

Comment: You can do it behind the scenes.  Put `func` in a module and add the parameter `parm` to specification portion of the module.  `func` will have access to `parm` via host association,  Perhaps, use the `protected` attribute.  Then, you can initialize `parm` prior to calling `vegas`.  `call init_parm(1.2345); call vega(....)`

Comment: @steve do you imply some using of global variables that are visible inside the function? Did I catch you thought?

Comment: @francescalus maybe. I have to think it over. Thank you!

Comment: @steve I have handled it. Your advice helped me. Thank you! I created a variable in a module that is used in my program. I initialize this variable outside of my function and use its value inside of the function. Very simple scheme, and I'm sad that I didn't invent it myself